# Chrome extension for holding your position on the page after auto refresh

Tags: google-chrome

I needed to keep refreshing a web page (not mine, the portal where I work)  to see new bookings. So I added a chrome extention to refresh the webpage after every 3 minutes. The problem is that after rfreshing, the page scrolls to the top of the screen. I have to manually scroll down to check if ny new bookings have come up. This defeats the purpose of auto refresh.
I found an extension that saves your place on the webpage, but that extension also takes you to the saved posiiton when you click on fetch, that is again manual intervention.
Are there any extensions that anyone knows of that will scroll the focus back on the point before page refresh. or any other solution for this situaiton?

I apologise if this is the wrong place for this post. Let me know and I will remove it.
Thanks in advance.

I have scoured the net for any such extention that will solve my problem but havent found any. I can't write a script and the website isn't mine so I can't change the code.